# .clone() and .remove() method in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My task is to achive the functionality, when I click on a button, then it add a full row, which is achived by me by .clone() method. Now I want to delete this. When I click on cross button, then only remove that line. As shown in image:[image]

When I click on cross, then remove that line. My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button#add").click(function(){   
    $(".abcd:last").clone().appendTo(".wrapper");  
});
$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function () {

        $(".abcd:last").remove();
    });

});
```

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
          <div class="form-group abcd" id="abcde">      
            <div class="col-sm-12" >
              <div class="btn-group week">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">All days
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="week"><a href="#">Monday</a></li><li class="week"><a href="#">Tuesday</a></li>
                  <li class="week"><a href="#">Wednesday</a></li><li class="week"><a href="#">Thusday</a></li>
                  <li class="week"><a href="#">Friday</a></li><li class="week"><a href="#">Saturdayy</a></li>
                  <li class="week"><a href="#">Sunday</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div> 
             <div class="btn-group week">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Time
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="week"><a href="#">Monday-saturaday</a></li>
                </ul>
             </div> 
             <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> : </label>
              <div class="btn-group week">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">.00
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="height: 10em;width:2em;  overflow: auto;">
                  <li class=""><a href="#">.00</a></li><li class=""><a href="#">.01</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#">.02</a></li><li class=""><a href="#">.03</a></li>                  
                  <li class=""><a href="#">.04</a></li><li class=""><a href="#">.05</a></li>                  
                  <li class=""><a href="#">.06</a></li><li class=""><a href="#">.07</a></li>                  
                </ul>
             </div>
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> to </label>
            <div class="btn-group week">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Time
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="week"><a href="#">Monday-saturaday</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> 
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1"> : </label>
            <div class="btn-group week">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">.00
                  <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="height: 10em;width:2em;  overflow: auto;">
                  <li class=""><a href="#">.00</a></li><li class=""><a href="#">.01</a></li>
                  <li class=""><a href="#">.02</a></li><li class=""><a href="#">.03</a></li>                  
                  <li class=""><a href="#">.04</a></li><li class=""><a href="#">.05</a></li>                  
                  <li class=""><a href="#">.06</a></li><li class=""><a href="#">.07</a></li>                  
                </ul>
             </div>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
          </div>
       </div>
       </div>
    </form>

     <button type="button" id="add" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Add</button>
    <button type="button" id="remove" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">remove</button>
```

I am able to add New line by click on add button, but unable to hide that line by click on cross.

Note: remove only that line, which line cross button is selected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, you'll need to change your clone to that :

```
$(".abcd:last").clone(true).appendTo(".wrapper");
```

Passing true mean that it is cloning events as well.

Then, in your remove function, you'll need to use `this` keyword. `this` will be the button clicked. You can then use DOM traversal method like closest to remove your row :

```
$(".glyphicon-remove").click(function () {

    $(this).closest(".abcd").remove();
});
```

Comment: You sure can, what is it?

Comment: Why we use .clone(true) ? instead of .clone()

Comment: As said in the answer, *"Passing true mean that it is cloning events as well."* Without passing true, the remove button wouldn't have any handler. Hence, it couldn't catch the click event.

Comment: You could use event delegation (`.on()`), but i recommend using clone true because it is faster!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, I've always used delegation (`.on())`, so thank you for explaining the use of passing `true` to `clone()`.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can bind the event to the container like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("button#add").click(function () {
            $(".abcd:last").clone().appendTo(".wrapper");
    });

    $(".wrapper").on('click', '.glyphicon-remove', function () {
            $(".abcd:last").remove();
    });

})
```