# when use JQuery clone() , why remove() not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clone

I use jquery clone() to copy table element , and I want to remove first td
there is my code , can any one help?

#### javascript

```
$.fn.hasAttr = function(name) {  
  return this.attr(name) !== undefined;
};
var arr_tr=new Array();
$('table tr').each(function(i){
  arr_tr[i].push($(this).clone());
});
//for some reason I need use like below
for(var x in arr_tr){
  for(var y in arr_tr[x]){
    if(arr_tr[x][y].find('td:eq(0)').hasAttr('rowspan')){//if td has rowspan attribute
    arr_tr[x][y].find('td:eq(0)').remove();//<== Why [<td rowspan=3>ABC</td>] can't remove
    };
  }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<table border=1 width='100%'>
<tr><td rowspan=3>ABC</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
<tr><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
<tr><td>C2</td><td>C3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/20635383/14945696

Comment: why you need to save clone inside array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify this down to just using an attribute selector:

```js
const $clone = $('table').clone();
$clone.find('td:first-child[rowspan]').remove();
$('#res').append($clone)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1 width='100%'>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=3>ABC</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>B2</td>
    <td>B3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td>C2</td>
    <td>C3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>CDE</td>
    <td>C4</td>
    <td>C5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>   
    <td>C6</td>
    <td>C7</td>
  </tr>
  
</table>

<h3>Result</h3>
<div id="res"></div>
```